# Expecting a timeout in QUnit

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit

I have an asynchronous QUnit test where the test should pass if the operation times out.  (I'm testing that if you omit an optional `errorCallback` and do something that throws an error, basically nothing happens no matter how long you wait.)

How would I do that?  If I use `Qunit.config.testTimeout` then the test will fail on timeout.  I want to set a timeout and have the test succeed when the timeout is reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just go with a `setTimeout` call making the test succeed?

e.g.:

```
expect(1);
stop();
doOperation(function () {
    start();
    ok(false, "should not have come back");
});
setTimeout(function () {
    start();
    ok(true);
}, timeoutValue);
```

Comment: Very nice!  I used this with three separate async tests, and cleared the timeout if all 3 completed before the timeout.  If the timeout triggered, I did a start(n) where n was the number of async callbacks that had not yet completed, to move the test along.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do in these cases (roughly):

```
function timeout(assert,to,error){
  var done = assert.async();
  var a = setTimeout(function(){
    assert.equal(to,undefined,error);
    done();
  },to); 
  return function(){
    done();
    clearTimeout(a);
  };
}
```

then you can:

```
...
var done = timeout(assert,2000,"not joined");
r.join(function(data){
    assert.ok(true,"join confirmed");
    done();
})
```

You may agument `timeout` function to `timeout(assert,to,toCB)` and execute the `toCB` instead of my dummy `assert.equal`